# reasons to not use typekit?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm launching a new site soon and would like to use a nice font (for headings etc). I've experimented with scripts like cufon and found them very disappointing. The way I see it, I have two legal options:

1. Create my own font stacks using fonts that are licensed for @font-face (like [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com))
2. Subscribe to typekit
3. Use standard font stacks including some of MS Office's nicer fonts (not keen on!)

I'm looking for comments from someone with experience here, not speculation please (I can do that myself!).

Has anyone used typekit? Have you noticed any performance issues?

Comment: Any specific reason you found cufon disappointing? sIFR has caused configuration and compatibility issues for our company, but we've found cufon great - especially when tied in with a little jQuery for ajax/dynamic content.

Comment: i found a slight delay, plus text is unselectable

Answer (score 1):

I used the typekit free trial, and loaded it using Google's webfont loader (which works with Typekit, Google fonts, and Ascender. I've never used Ascender, but found Typekit and Google fonts to be of about equal speed. This speed was not enough to deter me from using it. I have a very lightweight website, so one large item didn't impact it too much, but given what broadband penetration is and how much processing power it seems to use I wouldn't dissuade you from using this. These font files are all smaller than most small .swf files and people don't balk at using those.

Also, in regards to Safari on Mac, I've noticed no issue with Google fonts and I'm curious if the javascript that @rvlanen references is the javascript in the typekit font loader. Google's webfont loader doesn't seem to have this issue.

Hope this helps

P.S. Link to Google Webfont loader: http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about performance, you could do testing with TypeKit's free preview account. They also have [public uptime and response stats](http://typekit.com/tour/scalability).

There is also the option of licencing fonts for hosting on your own server. [FontShop](http://www.fontshop.com/blog/?cat=80) will sell you a set of WOFF+EOT fonts for a one-off price, but that will only work in IE and FF 3.6+ at the moment. You can also transfer the purchase to a free TypeKit account, which will cover Chrome + Safari too.

Comment: thanks, yes i've looked into all these options. Fontsquirrel off good eot and otf font kits for hosting your own licensed fonts.

Sorry i should have been more clear, i'm looking for someone that has used TypeKit in a busy, functional site for a period of time.

I've tried the trial and seems very responsive, but u always like opinions on these things from someone that's properly tried!

Answer (score 0):

Typekit doesn't work in Chrome for Mac when using HTML5 markup. Apparently this has to do with the way their JavaScript works. Read more about it [here](http://getsatisfaction.com/typekit/topics/typekit_fonts_rendering_problem_in_chrome).

Comment: Commenting from the future: I'm not sure since when it started working but I can confirm that "now" it works.